# C++ different outputs

Tags: c++

The `sizeof()` function should return the number of bytes of the argument passed to it. How there are different outputs for the `sizeof()` function while the arguments are essentially same?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main( )
{
    int b[3][2];
    cout<<sizeof(b)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(b+0)<<endl;
    cout<<sizeof(*(b+0))<<endl;
    // the next line prints 0012FF68
    cout<<"The address of b is: "<<b<<endl;
    cout<<"The address of b+1 is: "<<b+1<<endl;
    cout<<"The address of &b is: "<<&b<<endl;
    cout<<"The address of &b+1 is: "<<&b+1<<endl<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: FYI, adding spaces around operators makes the program easier to read and has no effect on the execution time and negligible time to the compilation.

Comment: It would be helpful to include the output of this program, and specifically call attention to the parts you find surprising and why you find them surprising (i.e. describe why you think the output should be something other than what it is.)  FYI: a when compiled for a typical 64-bit architecture, this might output something like `24 8 8 0x7fff00000010 0x7fff00000018 0x7fff00000010 0x7fff00000028`

Comment: Your claim that the arguments are "essentially same" is false, as the arguments have distinct and different types.   The `sizeof` operator , when given an expression (or the name of an object), gives the size of *the type of* its operand (and doesn't actually evaluate the operand).    Work out what the types of `b`, `b+0`, and `*(b+0)` actually are (hint: they are all DIFFERENT) and you will also then have an explanation of why `sizeof` gives different results.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sizeof(b)
```

This is the size of the entire `b` object, in bytes. `b` is an array of `int`s, a 3x2 array, so this is `sizeof(int)*3*2`.

```
sizeof(b+0)
```

When used in an expression, an array object decays to a pointer to the first value in the array. That is: any expression. Adding 0 to something is an expression. This is `sizeof(int (*)[2])`.

```
sizeof(*(b+0))
```

The array contains an array `int`s. Dereferencing a pointer to the first value of this array, or any other value in the array, gives an `int`. This is `sizeof(int[2])`.

And that's why all of these are different. "Essentially same" is not good enough, when C++ is concerned. C++ has no room for error, zero tolerance. If something is not exactly the same, then it is not the same. The End.

Comment: Correction to the last line. `sizeof(*(b+0))` is essentially `sizeof(b[0])`. Since b is a 2D array, this is `sizeof(int[2])` not `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Why, it certainly is.

Comment: `sizeof(b + 0)` does not compute `sizeof(int *)`.   It computes `sizeof(int(*)[2])`.